# Evaluate image segmentation with the absence of ground truth

Tags: validation, image-segmentation

Motivation: 
- Evaluate the computerised image segmentation against manual segmentation; 
- Evaluate the difference between difference manual segmentation.

Background:
Given a raw medical image (mammogram image), as seen (labelled as 'Raw image' in top left) in the graph below, we would like to segment out the orange tissue.

Five medical experts made independent segmentation on this image, resulting in five different segmentation, as seen in the row 'Manual segmentation'.

We also tested three computerised algorithm, resulting in three segmentation, as seen in the row 'Auto algorithm segmentation'.

Question:
- How to evaluate the difference between different manual segmentation?
- How to evaluate the accuracy of computersied segmentation?

My thought:
- A direct similarity measure of segmentation shape or area may not be appropriate. Because there's naturally no ground truth existing for a medical image segmentation. Furthermore, subtle difference won't be exposed in such measures.

[image]